# Angular [hidden] doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular

I have userPermission() function that works correctly, but component app-chat that depends on it always shows, even if userPermission() return false.

home.ts file

```
async userPermission(channel, channelId) {
    if (channel === undefined) {
        return false;
    } else if (channelId && channel.status === 'open') {
        return true;
    } else if (channelId && channel.status === 'private' && await this.inChannel(channelId)) {
        console.log('private have permission');
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

home.html file:

```
<app-chat [hidden]="!userPermission(channel, channelId) | async" [channelId]="channelId" [channel]="channel"></app-chat>
```

I also wrote

```
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried ngClass ?

Comment: I've tried, but same result.

Comment: Try `[hidden]="!(userPermission(channel, channelId) | async)"`. Or reverse the method result and use: `[hidden]="userNotAllowed(channel, channelId) | async"`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to apply an attribute conditionally.

You have to assign a value to make the attribute appear on the DOM element, and assign `undefined` to remove it from the DOM element.

```
<app-chat [attr.hidden]="!userPermission(channel, channelId) ? true : undefined" [channelId]="channelId" [channel]="channel"></app-chat>
```

Personally, I don't like this approach. It's easier to just use CSS classes.

```
<app-chat [class.hidden]="!userPermission(channel, channelId)" [channelId]="channelId" [channel]="channel"></app-chat>
```

CSS

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

**FYI**: `async` is for observables and promises only.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't work either. App-chat component always loading.

Comment: You did not ask for it **not to load**. You asked for it not to be shown. Use **ngIf** instead and read the "Getting start" tutorial in the document.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that it shows anyway. I've tried ngIf with same result.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like,

```
<app-chat [hidden]="!userPermission(channel, channelId | async )" [channelId]="channelId" [channel]="channel"></app-chat>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work. Now it returns `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '-LEAgSiXK-FL7b_ggO1Z' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'` where  `-LEAgSiXK-FL7b_ggO1Z` is the channelId

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be a problem with the type of the response. Try to compare with `== 'true'` or `=== 'true'` etc. I had such issues a time ago.

The problem could be: when 'false' is a string, it will return `true` (as string always returning true). In your case you are comparing to `!true` and that will be `false`.

```
<app-chat [hidden]="userPermission(channel, channelId) != true | async" [channelId]="channelId" [channel]="channel"></app-chat>
```

Maybe I´m wrong, but it could be an issue. Else provide an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar.

**Update**

Try to do the asych on the params inside the function if this are your observables

```
userPermission( (channel | asynch), (channelId | asynch)
```

**Update2**

Seem your vars are whether an Observable or return of an Promise you should use

`[hidden]="!userPermission(channel, channelId)"`

without asynch. As you can see in your error message it is returning `'true'` as wrong param for the pipe asynch.

Comment: Thanks, but it return `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

Comment: @ИванСидоров and also != 'true' ?

Comment: @ИванСидоров want to create a code snippet in your prefered tool? Codepen or what you like...

Comment: If you build your app does it work? I mean can you see your changes in the live source code?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the CSS attribute "visibility" in your html file.
The general case is:

```
<div [style.visibility]="'visible'"></div>
```

or

```
<div [style.visibility]="'hidden'"></div>
```

By using this with your example, this should work:

```
<app-chat [style.visibility]="!userPermission(channel, channelId) ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></app-chat>
```